# Nginx redirect all www to @

Tags: nginx, server

I have a multidomain Magento 2 site up. I never use www and have set up cname to @ with dns for each domain but I need a way to redirect all www requests to @ regardless domain. Is there a way to setup nginx server block this way?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is what you looking for:

```
if ( $host ~* ^www\.(.+) ) {
    set $domain_only $1;
    return 301 $scheme://$domain_only$request_uri;
}
```

You could create file with this rule and include it in your configs.

UPD:

I recommend you to use something like this:

```
server {
    listen XX.XX.XX.XX:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen XX.XX.XX.XX:443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    if ( $host ~* ^www\.(.+) ) {
    set $domain_only $1;
    return 301 $scheme://$domain_only$request_uri;
    }
...
```

Comment: @KakiSami yes, it should be in server block.

Comment: It works great but only for unsecure www.domain.com not secure www.domain.com. What can I do so it works

Comment: @KakiSami did you add this code to server block with secure domain?

Comment: I put it in a server block on itself, should it have listen 80; listen 443?

Comment: @KakiSami it should be on both servers( 80 and 443 ). If you have access to NS setting for this domains, you can create CNAME record www -> @. And it will solve your issue.

Comment: Do I need a SSL certificate for the www?

Comment: @KakiSami ssl certificate covers www.example.com and example.com. So you just need to setup it properly. You don't need special certificate for www.example.com.